# INSERT IGNORE INTO and UPDATE in one statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm running a script which serves downloads to my users. I would like to monitor their traffic on a per byte level, and I hold how many bytes they've downloaded in `$bytes`. I want to log it to my database and I'm using the following function:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    global $bytes;

    /* Save the traffic to the database */
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
    $st = $db->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO `stats`
                        SET `date` = CURDATE(), `bytes` = :bytes');
    $st->bindParam(':bytes', $bytes);
    $st->execute();
    $st = null;
    $db = null;
});
```

This query seems to work once, when the download is complete there's a new record in the table with the following data:

```
   date      |    bytes
------------------------
2013-02-03   |   2799469
```

however, on every other download the `bytes` field doesn't change. No new records and no change to the record that's already in the table. It's pretty obvious what the problem is, the query tries to insert a record but if it already exists then it aborts. I need an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE `stats`
SET `bytes` = `bytes` + :bytes
WHERE `date` = CURDATE()
```

but I would like to do the entire operation in one query. A query that will create the record if it doesn't exist and if it does exist, update the existing record.

Can this be done or am I going to have to run two queries on every download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. You can read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Your query would look something like this.

```
$st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `STATS`
VALUES('CURDATE()', :bytes)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `BYTES` = `BYTES` + :bytes");
```

You also should avoid using `INSERT IGNORE INTO` because in case of duplicate rows, no error will be generated, but only a warning.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting an SQL error with that query. It's saying there's an error near `SET `bytes` = `bytes` + 1024`

Comment: That looks like a case of misplaced quotes.

Comment: None that I can see... all the quotes have their ending quotes :/ http://pastebin.com/CqPKTZwz

Comment: Edit: found the problem, it has to be `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `BYTES` = `BYTES` + :bytes")`, not `SET`. Thanks!

Comment: Well, time to go brush up my own SQL. Reflected the change in the answer.